# Change value of other options, after selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://fiddle.jshell.net/stealthpancakes/qc8pwsze/3/

I want to change value of all options to '0' except selected option. 

For example, If I choose in the first place *Biology* and then *Chemistry* then  value of *Chemistry* and other options, except *Biology* should be '0'.
So I choose **first** *Biology* and *Chemistry* and for both 'level2', hit 'calculate' button, then result should be: 50/100, not 80/100.

So far I managed to add this code:

```
$('select[name*="select-subject"]').change(function() {

    $('option').not("option:selected").each(function() {
        $(this).val('0');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should specify to which `select` the option belongs:

```
$('select[name*="select-subject"]').change(function() {
    $(this).find('option:not(:selected)').each(function() {
        $(this).val('0');
    });
});
```